# Why is the difference between 2 streamlines is the flow rate per width?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow

So is there any intuitive explanation why is the difference of a stream function at two different points is the flow rate per width at the same time? Kinda confusing..

Answer (score 1):

A stream function is just a scalar function whose gradient is perpendicular to the flow, and the magnitude of whose gradient is the speed. If you define $x’$ to be a coordinate locally perpendicular to the flow, the average speed over a small interval $\Delta x’$ is $v\approx\frac{\Delta \psi}{\Delta x’}$.  The flux between two points is $F=v\Delta x’\approx\Delta \psi$.

Comment: I get it mathematically but hard to get intuitive understanding sometimes..tnx anyway